# dotnet tool install hangs in sdk:8.0.100-bookworm-slim

Tags: .net, docker, dotnet-tool

I am migrating an application from NET6 to NET8. The application is build within a dockerfile. For code analyis the dotnet tool "dotnet-sonarscanner" is installed in the build image.

In NET6 I use sdk:6.0.300-bullseye-slim as the build image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.300-bullseye-slim AS build
```

The command

```
RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-sonarscanner --global
```

works fine.

In NET8 I use sdk:8.0.100-bookworm-slim as the build image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.100-bookworm-slim AS build
```

Here, dotnet tool install hangs forever (or at least a couple of hours...) with no text output.

Things I have tried:

1. Different tool (dotnetsay) ... same results
2. Verbose level  -v diag ... still no output

The dockerfile is build with buildah in Jenkins. However, since the old build works fine I think this is probably a problem with the image sdk:8.0.100-bookworm-slim. What can I try to narrow this down?